# Error while processing route on ie8- js promises

Tags: internet-explorer, ember.js, ember-cli, ie8-compatibility-mode

i am using

ember: 1.8.1
ember data: 1.0.0-beta.12
ember-cli : 0.1.7

```
OfferRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: (params)->
    @store.find('offer',params.offer_id)
```

it works fine on Chrome but on IE8 i get "Error while processing route"

I think the issue is with the `@store`because if i use a json object instead of ```@store.find´´´work fine. Maybe something related with IE8 and js promises?

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue with cors ajax requests on Ie8. So far Ember, ember-cli support Ie8.

On development i use ember server --proxy=http://api.server.com as a work around

Comment: Have you found out what was the CORS issue? It seems like I'm having the same problem but network capture in IE9 doesn't show the CORS requests.